# Edit images in wwwroot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a programmer at mvc,
My goal is to use the image I have in the database and edit it into another image that does not necessarily exist in my wwwroot but in my computer.
image: [image]

Explanation of the image: I have an image in the database here and I want to edit it
Click the edit button
Edit image: [image]

But when I press the save button I get an error:
NullReferenceException: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object. PetShop.Client.Services.FileService.File(CreateAnimalViewModel model) in FileService.cs var path = Path.Combine(wwwPath, "Images", model.Photo!.FileName); PetShop.Client.Controllers.AdminController.EditAnimal(CreateAnimalViewModel model) in AdminController.cs  await _file.File(model);`

**Must note that the code of the service does work when I try to add a new image to wwwroot but does not work in edit**

My Service:

```
public class FileService : IFileService
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;
    public FileService(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }
    public async Task<string> File([FromForm] CreateAnimalViewModel model)
    {
        string wwwPath = _environment.WebRootPath;
        var path = Path.Combine(wwwPath, "Images", model.Photo!.FileName);
        if (model.Photo.Length > 0)
        {
            using var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            await model.Photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
          return model.Animal!.PhotoUrl = model.Photo.FileName;
    }
}
public interface IFileService
{
    Task<string> File([FromForm] CreateAnimalViewModel model);
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class CreateAnimalViewModel
{
    public Animal? Animal { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditAnimal(int id)
    {
        var animal = await _repo.FindAnimalById(id); 
        ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(_repository.GetCategoriesTable(), "CategoryId", "Name");
        return View(new CreateAnimalViewModel() { Animal = animal});
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditAnimal([FromForm] CreateAnimalViewModel model)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        TryValidateModel(model);

        await _file.File(model);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _repo.EditAnimal(model.Animal!);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Manager));
        }
        return View();
    }
```

My View:

```
@model PetShop.Client.Models.CreateAnimalViewModel

<div >
<form asp-action="EditAnimal" method="post" >
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div><input type="hidden" asp-for="Animal!.AnimalId" id="Space"/>
<dl class="row" >
    <dt class = "col-sm-2"><label asp-for="Animal!.Name" id="Space"></label></dt>
    <dd class = "col-sm-10"><input asp-for="Animal!.Name"/><span asp-validation-for="Animal!.Name" ></span></dd>
    <dt class = "col-sm-2"><label asp-for="Animal!.BirthDate" id="Space"></label></dt>
    <dd class = "col-sm-10"><input asp-for="Animal!.BirthDate"/><span asp-validation-for="Animal!.BirthDate"></span></dd>
    <dt class = "col-sm-2"><label asp-for="Animal!.Description" id="Space"></label></dt>
    <dd class = "col-sm-10"><input asp-for="Animal!.Description"/><span asp-validation-for="Animal!.Description"></span></dd>
    <dt class = "col-sm-2"><label asp-for="Animal!.CategoryId" id="Space"></label></dt>
    <dd class = "col-sm-10"><select asp-for="Animal!.CategoryId" asp-items="ViewBag.Category"></select><span asp-validation-for="Animal!.CategoryId"></span></dd>
    <dt class = "col-sm-2"><label asp-for="Photo"></label></dt>
    <dd class = "col-sm-10"><input type="file" asp-for="Photo" accept="image/*"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="Photo"></span></dd>
    <br/> <br/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="ButtonDesign"/>
</dl>
</form>
    <a asp-action="Commands"><input type="submit" value="Back to Admin Page" id="BackPageButton"/></a>
```

**In view I only show the part of the file all the other things are not relevant to the problem**

**Edit post**
Repository:

```
 public async Task<int> AddAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        _context.Add(animal!);
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task<int> EditAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        _context.Update(animal);
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

public DbSet<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        var category = _context.Categories;
        return category;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't given the database information. Also provide the code which can help to reproduce to load this page so that can be started from here

Comment: The concept is when you would load this page, first need to check the image path with the existing database information like this way,  `string checkFile = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "FolderName", "ImageNameMapInDatabase.png"));` here you have to check if that exist, other then you will get `exception` as you are getting

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron What you wrote I can not fall into error?

Comment: If you can check `checkFile` is that empty then you shouldn't encounter exception, in your code on `File` method set conditional on `path` not null or empty

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Okay but will that also solve my problem of editing a photo?

Comment: Man, edit means you would like to replace existing image or if doesn't exist want to upload new one, you would first load that `Id` then with that `Id or Name` which are are going to modify then  upload new picture and replace with that by the `Id` you have that it.

Comment: Better upload your project somewhere and share the link so that it can be check dierctly because your current code is incomplete to simulate.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I tried to do what you wrote down: **string path = Path.GetFullPath (Path.Combine (wwwPath, "Images", model.Photo! .FileName));**

And I made the same error

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes, it gets a file (it works for me when I try to add a picture to a new animal)

Comment: Share relavant code other then cannot proceed as the comment getting larger.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I wrote all the relevant code in the post

Comment: `_repo` and `_repository.GetCategoriesTable()` reference is missing, Adding view also missing, edit view also missing, how can be moved further.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I added all the repository at the end of the post
And also the view in full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's begin with your mistaken code below,

**[FromForm] In EditAnimal Post Method:**

You are submitting `[FormBody]` but here you are receiving `[FromForm]` this is one of the reason of your null reference exception. In your case you needn't to use that instead your can directly use `class`.

**Photo has no handler in controller**

You are sending image file from your view. But your controller doesn't have any handler for that. It should have `IFormFile` type to receive image.

**So wrong way:**

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditAnimal([FromForm] CreateAnimalViewModel model)
    {
        
    }
```

Based on your correct design and architecture this is not correct way.

**Correct way:**

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditAnimal(CreateAnimalViewModel model, IFormFile photo)
    {
        if (photo == null || photo.Length == 0)
        {
            return Content("File not selected");
        }
        var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "images", photo.FileName);
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
        
        model.Animal!.PhotoUrl = model.Photo!.FileName;
       
        
        // Find the existing data
        var objAnimal = _context.Animals.Where(aId => aId.AnimalId == model.Animal.AnimalId).FirstOrDefault();


       if(model != null)
        {
            //Update the date with new value
            objAnimal!.AnimalId = model.Animal.AnimalId;
            objAnimal.Name = model.Animal.Name;
            objAnimal.Category = model.Animal.Category;
            objAnimal.Description = model.Animal.Description;
            objAnimal.PhotoUrl = model.Animal.PhotoUrl;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }


        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = model!.Animal.AnimalId });

    }
```

**Edit method when loading:**

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
        {
            var animal = await _context.Animals.FindAsync(id);
            ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(_repository.GetCategoriesTable(), "CategoryId", "Name");
            return View(new CreateAnimalViewModel() { Animal = animal, DisplayPhoto = animal!.PhotoUrl });
          
        }
```

Here you have made another mistake, there is no point of using `CreateAnimalViewModel` rather you can directly return `Animal Model`, as you decided to use `CreateAnimalViewModel` in that case, the way you are binding `Animal domain class` to `CreateAnimalViewModel` you would lose `PhotoUrl` so here I have introduced another property in View Model to avoid extra modification which I will be using to load image on `view`.

So the updated `CreateAnimalViewModel` would be:

```cs
public class CreateAnimalViewModel
    {
        public Animal? Animal { get; set; }
        public string? DisplayPhoto { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? Photo { get; set; }
    }
```

If you can use single `ViewModel` for this `view` in that case `IFormFile? Photo property`  is also not required, you can directly bind the `image` in view. But I didn't modify your existing anything.

**View For loading Edit Animal:**

```cs
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.CreateAnimalViewModel
<div>
    <form asp-action="EditAnimal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div><input type="hidden" asp-for="Animal!.AnimalId" id="Space" />
        <div>
            <h4><strong>Animal Details</strong> </h4>

            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">

                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="Animal!.Name"></label></th>
                    <td> <input asp-for="Animal!.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter animal name" /><span asp-validation-for="Animal!.Name"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="Animal!.Description"></label></th>
                    <td> <input asp-for="Animal!.Description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter animal description" /><span asp-validation-for="Animal!.Description"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="Animal!.Category"></label></th>
                    <td> <input asp-for="Animal!.Category" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter animal category" /><span asp-validation-for="Animal!.Category"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> <label asp-for="Photo"></label></th>
                    <td>
                        <img src="~/images/@Model.Animal!.PhotoUrl"
                             class="rounded-square"
                             height="50" width="75"
                             style="border:1px"
                             asp-append-version="true" accept="image/*" />
                        <input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:107px" >Update</button></th>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.ActionLink("Back To List", "Index", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })</th>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

**Final output:**

[image]

This should fix your exception.

Comment: It works for me but I wanted to ask you to view the image why the image does not change to the image I replace and another question is it also suitable for the function of adding a new animal part of the file?